# Python Genetic Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, simulation, genetic-algorithm

I've made this to pick the LQR parameters for my self balancing robots simulation. So to break down what I have done,

**Randomly Create Population**

1. I create a random population. The population is a list of lists having 4 parameters each of which is randomly generated. But I have applied bounds for them using the values I got from my manual tuning for my simulation.

   ```
    def population_create(p_size,geno_size,bounds):

    p = [ random_param(geno_size,bounds) for i in range(p_size)]
    return p



   def random_param(g,b):
        return [random.uniform(b[i][0],b[i][1]) for i in range(g)]
   ```

**Try it on Robot and Evaluate**

2.Then I evaluate each parameter to see how much the wheels have rotated and how much the robot is inclined after one minute.

`fitness = encoder_readings + tilt`

So the closer the fitness is to zero the better the robot balances.
This is done for the whole population

**Create next generation**

3.Then I make the next generation with Mutation, Crossover and passing healthy individuals directly.

```
def population_reproduce(p,fitness):

    size_p = len(p)
    new_p = []
    
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Param":p,"Fitness":fitness})
    dataframe = dataframe.sort_values(['Fitness'])
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)    

    sorted_p = dataframe['Param'].tolist()

    elite_part = round(ELITE_PART*size_p)
    new_p = new_p + sorted_p[:elite_part]

    for i in range(size_p-elite_part):
        mom = p[random.randint(0,size_p-1)]
        dad = p[random.randint(0,size_p-1)]
        child = crossover(mom,dad)
        child = mutate(child)
        new_p.append(child)
    
    return new_p
```

```
def crossover(p1,p2):
    
    crossover = []
    locii = [random.randint(0,8) for _ in range(len(p1))]
    
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        if locii[i]>4:
            crossover.append(p2[i])
        else:
            crossover.append(p1[i])
        
    return crossover

def mutate(c):
    size = len(c)
    for i in range(size):
        if random.random()< MUTATION_PROBABILITY:
            c[i] += random.gauss(c[i]/50,MUTATION_DEVIATION)
            
    return c
```

This continues for some generations.

These are the links to the full codes.

[Genetic Algorithm Supervisor](https://pastebin.com/CRhbazWr)

[Population Script](https://pastebin.com/4R9sKe18)

[Robot Controller](https://pastebin.com/ttjqGz9p)

I would very much appreciate if you could take a look and let me know if this is a correct implementation of a genetic algorithm.

One observation I made is that the fitness doesn't converge to a lower value after each iteration. It randomly goes up and down. Could this be because of some inconsistency in my stimulation on Webots or is it a mistake in my code thats causing this?

Comment: Hey there, I'm under the impression this community is for reviewing code that is working, and not necessarily to check the correctness of your code :)

Comment: I'm sorry if this isn't the place I should be posting this. This code does work. I'm not sure how much I could call this a genetic algorithm? Because most genetic algorithms I've seen tend to converge(get fitter over each iteration).Though mine works it doesn't necessarily converge like the others. So I was expecting if someone could help me improve this like giving me some ideas. Thanks @RGS

Answer (score 1):

**On the style of the code**:

While I'm not saying the code is or isn't correct, there's some small tweaks you could make it to improve it's legibility:

**Spacing**

Write code like you would write English (in some sense :P). After commas you needs spaces, so do

- `def crossover(p1, p2):` instead of `def crossover(p1,p2):`;
- `random.uniform(b[i][0], b[i][1])` instead of `random.uniform(b[i][0],b[i][1])`
- same thing around binary ops: `if locii[i] > 4:` instead of `if locii[i]>4:`
- etc.

List comprehensions often do not need a leading space, so you can go with

```
p = [random_param(geno_size, bounds) for i in range(p_size)]
```

instead of

```
p = [ random_param(geno_size,bounds) for i in range(p_size)]
```

**`crossover`**

You have written:

```py
def crossover(p1,p2):
    
    crossover = []
    locii = [random.randint(0,8) for _ in range(len(p1))]
    
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        if locii[i]>4:
            crossover.append(p2[i])
        else:
            crossover.append(p1[i])
        
    return crossover
```

Consider this alternative definition:

```py
def crossover(p1, p2):
    
    crossover = []
    for p1_elem, p2_elem in zip(p1, p2):
        if random.randint(0,8) > 4:
            crossover.append(p2_elem)
        else:
            crossover.append(p1_elem)
        
    return crossover
```

Notice I don't precompute all `locii`, although you could do that, of course. Also note the usage of `zip` which means I can traverse both `p1` and `p2`, instead of having to use indices to later grab the values. (You can read more about `zip` and find other tips and tricks [here](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/zip-up).

**`random_param`**

In line with one of the things I showed above, instead of doing

```py
def random_param(g,b):
     return [random.uniform(b[i][0],b[i][1]) for i in range(g)]
```

you could iterate directly over `b`:

```py
def random_param(g, b):
     return [random.uniform(bs[0], bs[1]) for bs in b]
```

(More on better iterating in Python [here](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/enumerate-me).)

Then, take that and unpack `bs` with `*` instead of with indices:

```py
def random_param(g, b):
     return [random.uniform(*bounds) for bounds in b]
```